# Unauthorized response when making http calls in parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, dotnet-httpclient

I have code where I loop through some services and call the api for those services.  If I run these calls one at a time, I get the response `StatusCode` of OK (200) for each call.  If I change the code to run in parallel, the first call finished gets an OK but the remaining calls all complete with a `StatusCode` value of Unauthorized (401).

What's weird is that all the calls are actually processed on the server -- even the calls where I get back an Unauthorized response.  I don't understand what is happening.

Here is the code I'm running.  (Parallel code is currently commented out)

```
using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;  // Use Windows Credentials
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        //Some services can run up to 1.5 minutes - need to ensure we don't time out
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);

        //Get Available Services
        Console.WriteLine("Retrieving service list ...");
        var result = await client.GetStringAsync(_baseURL);

        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Service> services = new List<Service>();
        services = jss.Deserialize<List<Service>>(result);
        Console.WriteLine(services.Count.ToString() + " services to run.");

        // ** Non Parallel Code **
        foreach(var service in services)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running " + service.Name);
            var _serviceResponse = await client.PostAsync(_baseURL + "/" + service.Id.ToString() + "/run", null);
            Console.WriteLine(service.Name + ": Response = " + _serviceResponse.StatusCode + "  " + _serviceResponse.ReasonPhrase);
        }

        //  ** Parallel Code **
        //await Task.WhenAll(services.Select(async s => {
        //        Console.WriteLine("Running " + s.Name);
        //        var _serviceResponse = await client.PostAsync(_baseURL + "/" + s.Id.ToString() + "/run", null);
        //        Console.WriteLine(s.Name + ": Response = " + _serviceResponse.StatusCode + "  " + _serviceResponse.ReasonPhrase);
        //}));
    }
}
```

}

From what I've read, `HttpClient` is supposed to be able to process simultaneous calls without problem when using Async (which I'm doing).  So I'm curious why it behaves differently with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the service I was calling didn't like that many requests coming that quickly.

I had to prime the online list with an upload and then use my code to only upload a small number of additions or deletions.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the server is applying some kind of rate limiting to client requests from the same IP/User, and returning 401 when the max is exceeded?

Comment: No.  At this point, I only have 3 services on the server -- so I'm only really making 3 calls.  Also, as I noted, the requests aren't really being rejected -- they are being handled and processed.  That's what makes it so confusing that I get back a Unauthorized.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to run Fiddler and see whether or not a 401 is really being returned (sounds like not, from the your server handler's perspective), or whether the client is somehow deciding that another type of error condition should look like a 401.

Comment: Good call!  So it appears there may be some kind of timing issue.  My first run on Fiddler showed all requests resulting in 200 which indicated maybe there was something going on in the client.  However, subsequent calls do indeed show a 200 response on the first request and 401 responses on the other two.

Comment: Are your Windows credentials perhaps not being propagated to the various threads in the async case, so handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true has no effect?

Comment: Its almost as if the client is timing out -- which I wouldn't expect since I set the `Timeout` to 3 minutes.  Now that I've run multiple times with Fiddler, I'm seeing very random behavior.  Sometimes only one completes with 200, sometimes 2 complete, and once all 3 completed with 200 response.

Comment: Well, if the tasks happen to execute on the launching thread, that could happen.  If  it is an authentication problem, you might see something by comparing the request headers for the failing requests to the successful ones.

Comment: Can you explain that one to me -- "if the tasks happen to execute on the launching thread, that could happen"?  I'm not following how that causes the problem -- or how to resolve that.